# Setting pipeline variable contains extraneous double or single quote

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I have the following command to set a `BASE_URL` variable in Azure DevOps yaml:

```
- script: |
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BASE_URL;]$(PROD-CONTAINER-URL)"
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master'))
```

However whenever I echo the variable then it looks like this:

`https://google.com"`

If I replace it with a single quote or put the `$(PROD-CONTAINER-URL)` inside or outside the quotes then the problem still persists. How can I get around this and what causes it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To solve this issue in Bash script, you need to remove double quotes or single quotes.

```
steps:
- script: |
     echo ##vso[task.setvariable variable=BASE_URL;]$(PROD-CONTAINER-URL)
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- script: |
    echo $(BASE_URL)
```

Then the `BASE_URL` variable will not contain the quotes.

[image]

Comment: is this a known and expected behaviour of Azure DevOps? Because it's best practice to use quotes. If it is a bug, please fix it.

Comment: This does not make sense, it is executing Windows command interpreter and not bash.

Comment: Removing the quotes it was interpreted as comment in my case. But might not be a problem in pipeline afterall.

Comment: Sorry but -1; I don't know why this is the accepted answer, without any quotes the remainder of the echo line is simply a comment in bash.   It might work on a Windows node when [steps.script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-script?)  is `cmd` but it won't work for `bash`.

Answer (score 7):

Just as in [kap's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75160876/22141712), I saw the same behavior this week and resolved by turning off bash debugging around the variable output lines, for example:

```
set +x
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BASE_URL;]$(PROD-CONTAINER-URL)"
set -x
```

Comment: This coupled with @kap 's explanation is the correct solution.

Answer (score 4):

Ultimately the root cause of this issue is that the output logs (raw logs) are parsed for lines containing the special mask `##vso` indicating a command to the pipeline environment. *Anything until the end of the line is taken into account*.

The are multiple reasons for this. One reason is that Windows command shell is used to evaluate Bash code, as in [Kevin Lu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62909204/2952093). The additional `"` of the echo commands will be given out and be considered part of the variable.

When using Bash correctly on a Linux environment, this can happen when debugging is on (`set -x`). The command `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BASE_URL;]$(PROD-CONTAINER-URL)"` actually produces two outputs:

```
+ echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=BASE_URL;]https://google.com'
##vso[task.setvariable variable=BASE_URL;]https://google.com
```

And it can happen that the wrong one is considered correct. I don't know how it is decided, but sometimes this happens, sometimes not.

There may be plenty of other reasons creating the same issue.

Comment: Probably M$ have a bug in their regex which parses out `##vso[` lines - they might consider anchoring to the start of line with `^` or something similar

Answer (score 3):

Fixed using powershell instead. Must be a bash escape issue I'm not aware of:

```
- powershell: |
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BASE_URL;]$(TEST-CONTAINER-URL)"
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'develop'))
  displayName: "Initialize test base url variable"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
The only thins we changed recently was the pool image to ubuntu-latest.
After this change the problem came out randomically, but not always.

Discovered that with the managed image ubuntu-18.04 the wrong quote is not there anymore:

```
  pool: 
  vmImage: ubuntu-18.04
```

Just discovered that this is always the case. Sometime it fails again, just with a very lower frequency.